# C# spawn manager creating waves of enemies too quickly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner making my first game in Unity, following Unity's Create With Code course. I'm creating a shooter game that will use hand tracking. I haven't set up hand tracking yet so i created an OnTrigger input that explodes objects when I hit space. I created the spawn manager below to spawn waves of enemy attack, but they all the waves are spawning enemies too fast. It seems like they're spawning automatically instead of when the first wave has been destroyed.

Is there an easier way to spawn at a slower rate? Or spawn only when there are no more enemies alive?

EDIT: Added Attack script below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Trumps;
    private float spawnRange = 9;
    public int enemyCount;
    public int waveNumber = 1;

    void Start()
    {      
        SpawnEnemyWave(waveNumber);
        //InvokeRepeating("GenerateSpawnPosition", startDelay, randomInterval); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        enemyCount = FindObjectsOfType<Attack>().Length;
         if(enemyCount == 0)
             {
                waveNumber++;
                SpawnEnemyWave(waveNumber);
             }
     }   

    void SpawnEnemyWave(int enemiesToSpawn)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < enemiesToSpawn; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(Trumps, GenerateSpawnPosition(), Trumps.transform.rotation);
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GenerateSpawnPosition()
     {
        float spawnPosX = Random.Range(-spawnRange, spawnRange);
        float spawnPosZ = Random.Range(-spawnRange, spawnRange);
        Vector3 randomPos = new Vector3(spawnPosX, 0, spawnPosZ);
        return randomPos;      
     }
    }
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Attack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 0.5f;
    public GameObject Player;
    private Rigidbody enemyRb;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemyRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        this.transform.LookAt(Player.transform);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Vector3 lookDirection = (Player.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
        enemyRb.AddForce(lookDirection * speed);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);


    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Game Over");
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is the `Attack` script actually attached to `Trumps`? You should probably rather make `Trumps` of type `Attack` just to be sure

Comment: This question may be more suited to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BrianRogers ah i didn't know that existed, i'll try gamedev. thank you

Comment: @derHugo thanks for your advice. Double checked and the attack script is attached to those prefabs but will do as you suggested as well

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can use the invoke method:

```
Invoke("NameOfTheMethod", 1f)
```

What this method does is that it waits a certain amount of seconds before calling a method. You have to write the name of the method in quotation marks and then select how long you want to wait before the method is called (The "1f" represents the delay in seconds.) In your case, you can make the script wait before spawning enemies.

Comment: and when exactly would you call this? ;)

Comment: I would assume that in his case he can call this method when there is a certain amount of enemies (i.e. if(enemies < 5) { Invoke("SpawnEnemies", 2f)}

Comment: Yeah but this would initialize an `Invoke` every frame while that condition is true so after the first `2` seconds you would get a new wave each frame ;)

Comment: True, but  he could also create a boolean to make sure that invoke only happens once every time that the condition is true.

Comment: Which is not that trivial here as you will see ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your `Attack` script but I would use something like

```
public class Attack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static readonly HashSet<Attack> AliveAttackInstances = new HashSet<Attack>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        AliveAttackInstances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        AliveAttackInstances.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

So you can all the time in a cheaper way check how many and which enemies are alive like

```
public class SpawnAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    // I would change this type here to make sure your spawned prefab actually 
    // HAS an Attack attached .. otherwise your enemyCount will always be 0
    public Attack Trumps;

    ...

    void Update()
    {
        if(Attack.AliveAttackInstances.Count == 0)
        {
            waveNumber++;
            SpawnEnemyWave(waveNumber);
        }
    }
```

---

Then in order to add a certain delay before spawning the next wave you could use a simple timer like

```
public class SpawnAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Attack Trumps;

    [SerializeField] private float delay = 1f;
    private float timer;

    ...

    void Update()
    {
        if(Attack.AliveAttackInstances.Count == 0)
        {
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if(timer <= 0)
            {
                timer = delay;

                waveNumber++;
                SpawnEnemyWave(waveNumber);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it possible the for loop is responsible for spawning too many enemies? Tried deleting the for loop but then 3 clones kept spawning and destroying themselves over and over again, instead of spawning a large number of clones. Now i'm thinking I need to add a time.deltatime to normalize the spawn code - though i'm not sure how to add it to the spawn code. Am i on track with any of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Coroutine.
Here's a video about Coroutines: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qolMYyq0nX0

My example:

```
public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour {

private float TimeToWait = 3f;

public int enemyCount = 0;

public int waveNumber = 0;

public GameObject enemy;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemyWave(waveNumber));
}

void Update()
{
    if (enemyCount == 0)
    {
        waveNumber++;
        StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemyWave(waveNumber));
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        enemyCount--;
    }
}

IEnumerator SpawnEnemyWave(int enemiesToSpawn)
{
    //"Things to do before the seconds."
    for (int i = 0; i < enemiesToSpawn; i++)
    {
        enemyCount++; 
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(TimeToWait); // at this example we wait 3 seconds (float TimeToWait = 3f;)

    //"Things to do after the seconds."

    for (int i = 0; i < enemiesToSpawn; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("New Enemy!");

        Instantiate(enemy, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i tried your code (modified the input), but none of the enemies spawned. I'll dig deeper into coroutines